# Ensuring consistent dependencies version in Maven

Tags: maven, dependency-management

In my project I have module `M1` it use library `A`. This library have dependency to library `B`.

And in another module `M2` I want to use library `B`.

And of course I have "root" module which depend on all my modules so versions of library `B` should be the same across all projects.

So I added `B` to dependency of my `M2` module but don't know how to specify it version because I need exactly same version as library `A` use.

If I specify current version of library `B` then when I will upgrade library `A` to new version I will forget to update version of `B` in my module.

Also I don't want to put `A` as dependency of `M2` because I need only limited part of it's functionality.

What is best practices for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maven enforce plugin can break the build if the versions diverge so that yo do not forget to update: see https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html

Comment: Does this work with a mixture of transitive and direct dependencies, too? Because we have such here: `M1` → `A` → `B`, `M2` → `B`.

Comment: I think it is best solution provided. Unfortunately I can't use it because one of library I use already have problem with consistency of used dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options some of them you exclude explicitely. Let me mention them for the sake of completeness anyway:

1. Include `B` as a dependency in `M2`.

   - *Advantage*: Cleanest solution with respect to adding only those functionality to `M2` that's actually needed.
   - *Disadvantage*: Version of `B` in `M2` has to be kept in sync with versin of `B` in `A` manually.
2. Include `A` as a dependency in `M2`.

   - *Advantage*: Central `<DependencyManagement>` can be used in your parent POM. Hence, Versions of `B` will always be the same in all sub-projects.
   - *Disadvantage*: Functionality of `A` not needed in `M2` is added to `M2`.
3. Include `M1` as a dependency in `M2`.

   - *Advantage*: `M2` always uses the same version of `B` as `A` without having to deal with `B` as a dependency at all.
   - *Disadvantage*: Functionality of `M1` and of `A` not needed in `M2` is added to `M2`.
4. Use [`<dependency>/.../<exclusion>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions) to exclude `B` from `A` in `M1`.

   - *Advantage*: Central `<DependencyManagement>` can be used in your parent POM. Hence, Versions of `B` will always be the same in all sub-projects.
   - *Disadvantage*: Version of `B` has to be kept in sync with version of `B` in `A` manually.

[Input is welcome in case there's anything else I haven't thought of.]

Try [Maven Enforcer Plugin's Dependency Convergence](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) mentioned by [Assen Kolov in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289426/1744774). If it works for a mixture of direct and transitive dependencies, like in your case, as well, I'd use it in conjunction with 1.